# What is 'Spectral Domain'?

Tags: optics, laser, spectroscopy

In a paper which deals with [optical coherence tomography](https://www.osapublishing.org/ol/abstract.cfm?uri=ol-30-18-2391) they say they are dealing in the spectral domain. What exactly does that mean?

Comment: Could it be this? "Spatially encoded frequency domain OCT (SEFD-OCT, *spectral domain* or Fourier domain OCT) extracts spectral information by distributing different optical frequencies onto a detector stripe (line-array CCD or CMOS) via a dispersive element", from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_coherence_tomography#Spatially_encoded

Answer (score 2):

Generically speaking, optics makes a distinction between the time domain, which deals with the explicit time dependence $E(t)$ of the electric field of the light, and the frequency domain, in which the core emphasis is shifted to the Fourier transform of the field,
$$
\tilde E(\omega) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int E(t) e^{i\omega t}\mathrm d t.
$$
The terms 'spectral domain' and 'frequency domain' are essentially interchangeable in this context.

In optical coherence tomography, you have a sample that you want to interrogate, and you examine the back-scattered radiation by manipulating it coherently and comparing it against a stable reference. Some of these manipulations are best seen as changes (such as delays) in the time domain, while other examples are best analyzed through the prism of $\tilde E(\omega)$; the latter are known as Fourier-domain / frequency-domain / spectral-domain techniques. (Unfortunately, it's hard to go into more detail, particularly for such a broad question, since the field of OCT is so broad and heterogeneous.)